# App Crashes when using a lib which uses RxJava on release only

Tags: android, rx-java, proguard, android-proguard

I have used [this](https://github.com/zfdang/android-multiple-images-selector) library in my app the library itself uses RxJava and it works perfectly in Debug APK. It works even on Release when Proguard obfuscation is disabled. But it stops working when I enable Proguard once I select an Image!

Here is the log:

> 08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818): Process:
>   com.domus.safariar.domus, PID: 17818 08-02 22:54:11.848:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17818): java.lang.InternalError 08-02 22:54:11.848:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess.addressOf(Unknown Source:14)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueueProducerFields.(Unknown
>   Source:4) 08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.(Unknown
>   Source:50) 08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):   at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.call(Unknown Source:22) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.call(Unknown Source:2) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    at
>   rx.Observable$2.call(Unknown Source:8) 08-02 22:54:11.848:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at rx.Observable$2.call(Unknown Source:2)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   rx.Observable.subscribe(Unknown Source:43) 08-02 22:54:11.848:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Unknown Source:0)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity.LoadFolderAndImages(Unknown
>   Source:36) 08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):   at
>   com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(Unknown
>   Source:48) 08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):   at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7429)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7280) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 08-02 22:54:11.848:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 08-02 22:54:11.848:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field producerIndex in class
>   Lrx/internal/util/unsafe/SpscArrayQueueProducerFields; (declaration of
>   'rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueueProducerFields' appears in
>   /data/app/com.domus.safariar.domus-P04AN9pLul9iY1dryJ3vXg==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
>   08-02 22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method) 08-02 22:54:11.848:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17818):  at
>   rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess.addressOf(Unknown Source:0) 08-02
>   22:54:11.848: E/AndroidRuntime(17818):    ... 22 more 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818): java.lang.InternalError
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess.addressOf(Unknown Source:14)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueueProducerFields.(Unknown
>   Source:4) 08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.(Unknown
>   Source:50) 08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):    at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.call(Unknown Source:22) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.call(Unknown Source:2) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   rx.Observable$2.call(Unknown Source:8) 08-02 22:54:11.849:
>   E/UncaughtException(17818):   at rx.Observable$2.call(Unknown Source:2)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   rx.Observable.subscribe(Unknown Source:43) 08-02 22:54:11.849:
>   E/UncaughtException(17818):   at rx.Observable.subscribe(Unknown
>   Source:0) 08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity.LoadFolderAndImages(Unknown
>   Source:36) 08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):    at
>   com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(Unknown
>   Source:48) 08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):    at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7429)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7280) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 08-02 22:54:11.849:
>   E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 08-02 22:54:11.849:
>   E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field producerIndex in class
>   Lrx/internal/util/unsafe/SpscArrayQueueProducerFields; (declaration of
>   'rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueueProducerFields' appears in
>   /data/app/com.domus.safariar.domus-P04AN9pLul9iY1dryJ3vXg==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
>   08-02 22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method) 08-02 22:54:11.849:
>   E/UncaughtException(17818):   at
>   rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess.addressOf(Unknown Source:0) 08-02
>   22:54:11.849: E/UncaughtException(17818):     ... 22 more

I have tried to add some Proguard rules to avoid crashing but it does not work:

```
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }

-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    long producerNode;
    long consumerNode;
}
    -keep class com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity**{*;}
    -keep class com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity$**{*;}
    -dontwarn com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity**{*;}
    -keep com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity.LoadFolderAndImages**{*;}
    -dontwarn com.zfdang.multiple_images_selector.ImagesSelectorActivity.LoadFolderAndImages**{*;}
    -keep class rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn**{*;}
    -dontwarn rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.**
```

Comment: Hi, R u facing this issue in Samsung device?, If yes please use the following line of code to disable rx.unsafe-disable
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && "samsung".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
    System.setProperty("rx.unsafe-disable", "True");
}`
Ref : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3097

Comment: I have tested that on Pixel 2 emulator also. It is still crashy

Comment: `-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}

-dontnote rx.internal.util.PlatformDependent`
Please try to add missing lines to your proguard rule. This might help.

Comment: thanks but it crashed again :(

Comment: Just added those lines to my app's proguard file not the module itself and now it is working! Would you please post it as an answer so I can mark it thanks

Comment: Great. Sure,Will do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.** 

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
 long producerIndex; 
long consumerIndex; 
} 
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef { rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode; 
} 
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef { rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode; 
} 
-dontnote rx.internal.util.PlatformDependent
```

Please try to add missing lines to your proguard rule.